# wireless mesh network with B.A.T.M.A.N

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, openwrt

I'm configuring two routers linksys wrt54gl running openwrt backfire 10.3, kernel 2.6. I was able to configure batman between both devices and I'm able to ping the bat0 ips.

I followed this tutorial https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/mesh.batman

My question is: Having router A and B talking batman, how do I connect normal devices with my network? Is my LAN bridged? My scenario is: I have a wireless client connecting via router A and accessing a service offered by some server running on LAN from router B. I'm able to see my "ad-hoc" network, but I'm not able to connect to it using wireless. My meshed network won't have connection with internet.

Comment: IIRC you should be able to create an access point on the same radio and bridge it to the BATMAN mesh. However, I can’t verify this atm. If that works, you could of course also bridge a regular LAN interface to the mesh network.

Comment: that's what I was thinking about. However I wasn't sure if it was possible. The design that I was thinking was: A (router with some LAN) ports connected ad-hoc with B (router with some LAN ports) If I want to offer wireless on the A side, I would cascade an AP in the LAN. LAN would then be bridged with mesh. For sure if possible to create a new access point on the same radio and bridge with mesh, would be easier.